# Navbar does not stick to the top (React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

I am trying to get my Navbar to scroll up a little before it sticks to the top on my home page. I have saved my navbar as a component as I'll be reusing it again throughout my entire website on different pages. However, I can't seem to get the navbar to stick on my homepage. Can someone please help me?

```
**Navbar.js**

import React from 'react'
import './style.css';



const Navbar = (props) => {


  return(
   
        <div className="page">
            
             <div className="banner"></div>

                <div className="navbar-scroll">
                   <div className="border"></div>

                     <nav className=" navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar">  
                         <div className="nav-link collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li> 
                              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
                              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>   
                         </div> 
                     </nav>
                     <div className="border"></div>
                     <div className="divider-below-nav"></div>
                </div>



            
       
        </div>

   )

 }


export default Navbar
```

```
**Navbar.css**


.page {
    position: relative;
 }

.border {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgb(136, 133, 133);
    height: 4px;
}

a.nav-link { 
    padding: 1rmb; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 3.5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem; 
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(70, 66, 66, 0.5);
}

 .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(56, 55, 55); 
}

.divider-below-nav {
    min-height: 42px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

.banner {
    background-color:orange;
    height: 24.5vh;    
}

.navbar-scroll {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```
**Home.js**


import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
import './style.css';



 const Home = (props) => {


    return(
   
      
         <div className="body">
      
           <Navbar/>
        
           <div className="divider2"></div>

           <div className="divider3"></div>

           <div className="divider4"></div>

           <div className="divider1"></div>

           <div className="divider4"></div>

           <div className="divider1"></div>

           <div className="divider4"></div>

        </div>

      ) 

    }

export default Home;
```

```
**Home.css**


.divider1 {
    min-height: 42px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

.divider2 {
    min-height: 86px;
    background-color: white;
}

.divider3 {
    min-height: 42px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 196, 151);
}

.divider4 {
    min-height: 255px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: I just could give you idea. Create listener into scroll event. get the current position of users scroll and compare to the position of your navbar. If the scroll position exceed the navbar (start position + navbar height), then modify the DOM to make it sticky. And u should also update the DOM if the user back to top, to make it not sticky again

Answer (score 0):

Sticky items have to be a direct child of the scrolling element. In this case your `navbar-scroll` is a child of `page` which is not scrolling, it's the `body` that is.

```css
.page {
    position: relative;
 }

.border {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgb(136, 133, 133);
    height: 4px;
}

a.nav-link { 
    padding: 1rmb; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 3.5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem; 
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(70, 66, 66, 0.5);
}

 .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(56, 55, 55); 
}

.divider-below-nav {
    min-height: 42px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

.banner {
    background-color:orange;
    height: 24.5vh;    
}

.navbar-scroll {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /*you'll need this so menu can have a background when above other elements*/
    background: white
}

.divider1 {
    min-height: 42px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

.divider2 {
    min-height: 86px;
    background-color: white;
}

.divider3 {
    min-height: 42px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 196, 151);
}

.divider4 {
    min-height: 255px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
      
       <div class="navbar-scroll">
                   <div class="border"></div>

                     <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar">  
                         <div class="nav-link collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li> 
                              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
                              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>   
                         </div> 
                     </nav>
                     <div class="border"></div>
                     <div class="divider-below-nav"></div>
                </div>
        
           <div class="divider2"></div>

           <div class="divider3"></div>

           <div class="divider4"></div>

           <div class="divider1"></div>

           <div class="divider4"></div>

           <div class="divider1"></div>

           <div class="divider4"></div>

        </div>
```